# Constraint Layout v1.1.0: layout_constraintHorizontal_weight = 0 not working anymore

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

If the weight (layout_constraintHorizontal_weight) of view *progress_remaining* is 0 and the weight of *progress* is 1 it is not working as before (and expected).

The view *progress* with weight 1 has width 0 and and *progress_remaining* with weight 0 takes over all the space.

With 0.0001 and 1 everything looks fine.

This problem occurcs with constraint layout v1.1.0 (worked before with v1.0.2)

Am I missing something? Bug?

Thx.

Example:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/header_image"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/progress_remaining"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/progress_remaining"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/header_image"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/progress"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 2 Jun 4, 2018 11:19PM

Marked as Fixed
Fixed in 1.1.1

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80149154